# Parse JSON Array in C# with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json

I have this json array http://pastebin.com/T5zML8f6
And this code for parsing

```
string jsonMagazineInfo = await ApiRequester.GetRequest("http://magapp.ru/magazines");
JArray a = JArray.Parse(jsonMagazineInfo);
```

But when I run it I have an error

```
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
```

How to solve this problem and parse my json array correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in your JSON: `"title":"ООО "Информа..` quote not escaped.